# jQuery DatePicker with Multiple Months Side-By-Side Layout Issue

Tags: jquery, datepicker, uidatepicker

We are trying to get two months showing side by side on a standard jQuery DatePicker control using jQuery UI 1.7.2 and jQuery 1.3.2.

Unfortunately, the calendars will only stack vertically, and as a side effect are twice as wied as they should be (ugly!)

Here is the code we are using to call it:

```
$('#element').datepicker({numberOfMonths:2,dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',minDate: new Date()});
```

We are using the standard jQuery style sheet and no other style sheets are affecting the control (according to Firebug).

Seemingly this was supposedly a CSS issue that was fixed in the jQuery DatePicker project (http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/2898), however we are still getting this issue in FF and IE.

Any thoughts on a fix? Thank you :D

Comment: if you can put it online, we might be able to inspect it with firebug or alike and finding the source of this.

Comment: I resolved this by moving to a wrapper for the jquery date plugin from the Filament Group. Here is the link http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/date_range_picker_using_jquery_ui_16_and_jquery_ui_css_framework/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was the best solution for the problem...
http://www.filamentgroup.com/examples/daterangepicker_v2/index3.php

After some hacking I was able to remove the nasty menu and just get the date picker showing.

Comment: If this link goes down your answer will be useless. Please try to include the relevant code **within** your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This can still be an issue in FireFox and version 4.0.4 of Date Picker.
Have a look in the javascript source code (jquery.datepick.js) around line 1809.
The code section looks like this:

```
    // Resize
    $('body').append(picker);
    var width = 0;
    picker.find(renderer.monthSelector).each(function() {
        width += $(this).outerWidth();
    });
```

and change the width from:

```
var width = 0;
```

to

```
var width = 0.5;
```

For me, that fixed FireFox (v3.6.x) laying out side-by-side and Chrome, IE, Safari etc still look great.